Motivation behind the technique to find MVUE of $3\theta_2^2$
This question if from Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics."
Exercise 7.7.11.
Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ be a random sample from a $N(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ distribution.
(a) Show that $E[(X_1 − \theta_1)^4] = 3\theta_2^2.$
(b) Find the MVUE of $3\theta_2^2$.
My attempt:
The joint complete sufficient statistics for $N(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ are $(\overline{X},S^2)$, the sample mean and sample variance. Similar to what was done here or here, it is pretty trivial to show (for part (b)) that
$$T = \cfrac{3(n-1)^2\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}{4\Gamma\left(\frac{n+3}{2}\right)}S^4,$$ where $S^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2}{n-1},$ the sample variance of the given random samples. For part (a), it is well known as to how we can find central moments using the mgf technique (see for instance here).
My question: Why did the authors ask part (a)? Usually, they do that to nudge the reader towards the method to solve part (b). Initially, I thought they were asking us to guess a function $T$ such that $\mathbb{E}(T) = 3\theta_2^2$ and T is a function of joint complete statistics $\pmb{Y}$ for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. That would naturally make $T$ the MVUE of $3\theta_2^2$. Specifically, they mention (page $448$) in the previous relevant section
"The Rao–Blackwell, Lehmann–Scheffe theory outlined in Sections $7.3$ and $7.4$
extends naturally to this vector case. Briefly, suppose $\delta = g(\pmb{\theta})$ is the parameter of interest and $\pmb{Y}$ is a vector of sufficient and complete statistics for $\pmb{\theta}$. Let $T$ be a statistic that is a function of $\pmb{Y}$, such as $T = T(\pmb{Y})$. If $E(T) = \delta$, then $T$ is the unique MVUE of $\delta$."
So how does part (a) motivate us to guess this function $T$?
Edit 1:
The SE post here shows an unbiased estimator for $\sigma^4 = \theta_2^2$ that seems to be similar to the form in part (a), namely
$$T' = \frac{n}{3\left(n-1\right)^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4$$
but is not the MVUE for $\theta_2^2$. Adding this comment just in case it is relevant.

The approach of the exercise is to find a MVUE for some non-standard descriptor $E[Y]$ of a distribution by applying a method of moments where we express the descriptor $E[Y]$ in terms of distribution parameters $\theta_i$ for which we know there exists estimates in terms of the sufficient statistics.

First describe it in terms of the more typically known parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
Replace the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ with sample statistics $\bar{X}$ and $S$ which are known to be sufficient statistics.
Figure out what the discrepancy is in the expectation value of the estimator found in this way and whether it can be adjusted by adding some factor.

In a way you have already answered the question yourself in an edit by linking to a different method to find a solution. The method of moments is the wrong direction when it equates $E[(X_1 − \theta_1)^4]$ to the observed 4th moment $ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4$. To find the MVUE, one should use the sufficient sample statistics.

How do you express $ \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4$
in terms of $\bar{X},S^2$

Trying to express $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4$ in terms of $\bar{X},S$ is the wrong approach. It is a different statistic using different information. It is like trying to express the sample median in terms of the sample mean. You can't.
So that's what part (a) does. Instead of trying to express $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4$ in terms of $\bar{X},S$, it makes you try to express (or rather estimate) $E[(X-\mu)^4]$ in terms of $\bar{X},S$ (via $\mu$ and $\sigma$).

Thanks a bunch for the answer. The part where you mentioned "that relate more directly to the sufficient statistics" is exactly where I failed. Ultimately, the MVUE for $3\theta_2^2$ ends up being a function of $S^2$. I have no idea how we could guess that starting from $E[(X_1-\theta_1)^4]$. Without part (a), I would have straightaway guessed that answer to part (b) would involve $S^4$ simply because $S^2$ is the MVUE for $\theta_2$ so by extension, most of us would guess MVUE of $3\theta_2^2$ would be a function of $(S^2)^2$. So what's the role of $E[(X_1-\theta_1)^4]$ in any of this?

The only way I see is that if there is a way to express $E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4]  = k \times E(S^4)$ where $k$ needs to be determined, then we have a way. Honestly, if that is what the authors had in mind, I don't know what to say. It is too tedious. Folks could directly guess the answer to be some multiple of $S^4$ and we'd be done with it by finding the adjustment factor directly without having to go through $E[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4]$ .

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr an approach to find a mvue for some non-standard  descriptor of distribution parameter is to 1 first describe it in terms of the more typically known parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ 2 replace the $mu$ and $\sigma$ with their estimators $\bar{x}$ and $S$ which are known to be sufficient statistics. 3 Figure out what the discrepancy is in the expectation value and whether it can be adjusted by adding some factor....

... Sure, you can skip the first step which the part (a) of the exercise helps with and directly consider the statistic $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^2\right)^2$ as estimator instead of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X\right)^4\right)$

That was exactly the issue I faced. How do you express $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4$ in terms of $\overline{X},S^2$? The only way I saw that was to expand $E(S^4) = E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2\right)^2\right]$ and figure out what the cross terms $E[\sum_{i \neq j}(X_i-\overline{X})^2(X_j-\overline{X})^2]$ equate to (which is what I referred to as being tedious). Is that what you had in mind? Kindly confirm.

@TryingHardToBecomeAGoodPrSlvr trying to express $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4$ in terms of $\bar{X},S$ is the wrong approach. It is a different statistic using different information. It is like trying to express the sample median in terms of the sample mean. You can't.

I made a mistake in my comment. We do not express $\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4$ in terms of $\overline{X},S^2$. We express $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4]$ in terms of that of $\overline{X},S^2$. Is that right? That will then require us to figure out the cross terms $E[\sum_{i \neq j}(X_i-\overline{X})^2(X_j-\overline{X})^2]$ right?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I had a mistake as well. Expressing $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4]$ is  not the approach from the exercise. It is $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^4]$ that you want to express in terms of $\bar{X}$, $S$. (and even that is not possible, you don't create an exact expression, instead you make an expression from $\bar{X}$, $S$ whose expectation value is equal to $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^4]$) and to do that, you can first express it in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
